# CMD/Batch: How to use the output of a FOR /F loop in another set of commands

Tags: http, batch-file, cmd, sonos

New to stackoverflow and coding in general. I was able to write a batch that parses a text file for a set of IP address of the sonos players on a network, I was also able to write a separate batch that uses those IP address to execute the HTTP command to turn the wifi off on all units at once, but I had to input all of the IP addresses from the first batch manually. I want to know if there's a way I can input the IP address automatically into the second batch file, or if there's a way I can write a single batch file which will do everything in one go. The example below is only dealing with 2 IPs, real world I would need this to work with 20+ so that's why I want to find a way to automate the input of the IPs

Any help is greatly appreciated!

First Batch: GetIPlist.bat

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "IP Address: *[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" AboutMySonos.txt') DO echo %%a
```

Which returns the following list of IPs:

```
192.168.2.174 
192.168.2.24
```

Second Batch: SonosWifiDefeat.bat

```
@echo off

start "http://IpAddress:1400/wifictrl?wifi=persist-off" 
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
start "http://IpAddress:1400/wifictrl?wifi=persist-off"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two!

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "IP Address: *[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" AboutMySonos.txt') DO (
    start "http://%%a:1400/wifictrl?wifi=persist-off" 
    ping %%a -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    start "http://%%a:1400/wifictrl?wifi=persist-off" 
)
```

Or, even better, use Powershell so you don't have `start` opening a hundred browser windows:

```
Select-String -path .\AboutMySonos.txt -pattern "IpAddress: (.*)" | ForEach {
  ip=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
  Invoke-RestMethod "http://$ip:1400/wifictrl?wifi=persist-off" 
  ping $ip -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
  Invoke-RestMethod "http://$ip:1400/wifictrl?wifi=persist-off" 
}
```